# Missing Spyder dependecies qtconsole

Tags: python, conda, spyder, qtconsole

After the latest Spyder update using

```sh
conda update conda
```

I have started getting an error message in a small window that pops up and says

```
You have missing dependencies!


# Mandatory:
qtconsole >=5.0.1 : 4.7.7 (NOK)

Please install them to avoid this message.

Note: Spyder could work without some of these dependencies, however to have a smooth experience when using Spyder we strongly recommend you to install all the listed missing dependencies.

Failing to install these dependencies might result in bugs. Please be sure that any found bugs are not the direct result of missing dependencies, prior to reporting a new issue.
```

What is annoying is that any attempt to update qtconsole doesn't change anything

```sh
pawel@laptop:~$ ./.local/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda update conda
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.

pawel@laptop:~$ ./.local/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda update qtconsole
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.
```

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me out

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
conda update anaconda
conda install qtconsole=5
```

Comment: Welcome to SO; thanks for your suggestion. Code only answers are discouraged on SO (see StackOverflow.com/help for more info). Quality answers typically highlight important bits of the solution & explain how/why is address/solves the OP's issue. Most upvotes are accrued over time as visitors learn something they can apply to their own coding issues. Consider editing your answer to add an explanation &/or add a link to relevant documentation, to improve the quality of your answer, to share info, knowledge, & help coders learn.